# How to get name of values counted when using count_values()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'letter':   ['A','A','B','B','C','C'],
                    'value':[  1,  2,  3,  3,  7,  5],
                    'state':['CA','WA','WA','WA','CA','NV']})
```

[image]

Count how many times a value appears in the `state` column:

```
df['state'].value_counts()
```

[image]

This is a `pandas.core.series.Series` (according to `type(df['state'].value_counts()`). So:

```
df['state'].value_counts()[0]
```

Only returns `3`, not `WA 3`.

How do I get the name of the entries `value_counts()` counts? ie how do I get `WA`?

---

*I intend this as a self-answered question, if there are better answers, they are welcome.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[]`

```
df['state'].value_counts()[[0]] # if would like return the index, add .index
WA    3
Name: state, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Can get the indeces of the `pandas.core.series.Series`, ie of `df['state'].value_counts()` object by:

```
df['state'].value_counts().index
```

which returns:

```
Index(['WA', 'CA', 'NV'], dtype='object')
```

of datatype `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index`. Form a list:

```
list(df['state'].value_counts().index)
```

giving:

```
['WA', 'CA', 'NV']
```